# <class 'OverflowError'>: int too long to convert

Tags: python, hex

Im trying to read memory of a program but I get error it says

```
from ReadWriteMemory import ReadWriteMemory

rwm = ReadWriteMemory()

process = rwm.get_process_by_name("Tutorial-x86_64.exe")
process.open()

baseaddress = 0x100000000+0x00325A70

pointer = process.get_pointer(baseaddress, offsets = [0x598, 0x28, 0x8, 0xF8, 0x18, 0x18, 0x7F8])
print(process.read(pointer))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\program\from ReadWriteMemory import ReadWriteMem.py", line 10, in <module>
    pointer = process.get_pointer(baseaddress, offsets = [0x598, 0x28, 0x8, 0xF8, 0x18, 0x18, 0x7F8])
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ReadWriteMemory\__init__.py", line 77, in get_pointer
    temp_address = self.read(lp_base_address)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\ReadWriteMemory\__init__.py", line 100, in read
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(self.handle, lp_base_address, lp_buffer,
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'OverflowError'>: int too long to convert
```

Comment: Are you running a 32-bit version of Python?  You can't read a 64-bit process memory fro a 32-bit process.  Where did you get that `baseaddress`?

Comment: says [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of `ReadWriteMemory` is too old.  This was fixed in September of 2020.  You might try `pip install --upgrade ReadWriteMemory`.  If that doesn't bring in the latest, then you'll need to edit the package, to apply the two changes to `__init__.py` shown in this patch to add `ctypes.c_void_p(...)`.

https://github.com/vsantiago113/ReadWriteMemory/commit/e8b2859349e41380b561f6115ee43f058323877a